# Edit button gone in Interactive Report Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

so im trying to create an interactive report using apex. Usually, it will automatically create CRUD operation in the report. But somehow, the edit button (pencil and paper icon) in my interactive report is gone and i don't know how to fix nor adding them manually. Before it was gone, I changed my IR to Classical report since after i upload the table, APEX doesn't show all the columns (only 8 out of 9 column showed). And after that, I return the table into IR since all the column showed, but this is where the problem started.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't change from IR to classic. That is what is causing it. If the columns don't show   in the report, run the report, click actions>  columns, add the columns. Then save the report as "default report"

Answer (score 2):

- go to report's **Attributes** properties tab (on the right hand side of the Page Designer screen)
- set the **Link** property to "Link to Custom target"
- target will be "page in this application"

  - choose it from list of values (or type it manually, if you know its number)
  - as you'll want to pass item(s) value(s) from the report to form page, set items

That's all.